# How to emulate ARM unaligned memory access exceptions?

Tags: linux, arm, qemu, memory-alignment

I'm writing a cross-platform application which works on x86 machines, but crashes with "Bus error" on the actual ARM hardware (Raspberypi 2) ...

```
[ 4105.019037] Alignment trap: not handling instruction edd37a00 at [<00014218>]
[ 4105.019059] Unhandled fault: alignment exception (0x001) at 0x0002814e
[ 4105.028227] pgd = b736c000
[ 4105.033347] [0002814e] *pgd=3708d835, *pte=335d075f, *ppte=335d0c7f
```

... but runs without any problems in [Qemu](https://www.qemu.org/).

I run this command to enable SIGBUS signal and notification in the kernel running under Qemu, but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

`echo 5 > /proc/cpu/alignment` [[2](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/arm/mem_alignment)]

How do I emulate these errors in Qemu (or in another free emulator)? I would like to be able to run my automated tests inside a continuous integration environment running on a x86 machine where I'm unable to use the actual hardware. Alternatively I could rent an ARM server but I would like to avoid this.

Later edit for further clarification: the instruction which causes this problem on the real hardware is also executed in the emulator where it seems to work without triggering any exceptions.

Comment: Is it possible that the code is executing garbage?  This will often result in an alignment trap.  So QEMU maybe fine, but you have a timing and/or other issue which causes random code to execute on the PI.  Just code a test case and see what QEMU does with an actual unaligned access.  It should at least log the event.

Comment: qemu is open source, one would hope it would emulate correctly, if not then just make it do that.

Comment: @artlessnoise The same code is executed on both the real hardware and the emulated Qemu system. The same instruction which causes the exception on the actual hardware doesn't seem to cause any problem in Qemu.

Comment: @old_timer I'm aware that Qemu is open-source since I also built the latest version from source (in case the older ones didn't have support for misalignment traps). I was hoping somebody had already a solution to this before I dig deeper into the code.

Comment: Related, see [Disable misaligned data fixups on x86_64 Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15233717/608639). I also wanted to see some of the sore spots on cross-platform code. The best I found so far is the Undefined Behavior santizer (UBsan). You engage it with `-fsanitize=undefined`.

Comment: *"... I could rent an ARM server but I would like to avoid this ..."* - Is this a free or open source project? If so, then you are eligible for a [GCC Compile Farm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/CompileFarm) account. It has x86, ARM, PPC and MIPS machines for testing. You can also get a [OpenCSW build farm](https://www.opencsw.org/extend-it/signup/to-upstream-maintainers/) account. OpenCSW  provides Sparc machines, and they are sensitive to alignment, too.

Comment: @GabiPascalau  How do I run some software is not what stackoverflow is for, there is a specific closure line item for that type of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QEMU does not currently emulate unaligned access traps for ARM guest code. This is a reflection of the fact that its traditional primary purpose is "run correct guest code as quickly as possible"; putting in alignment traps slows down correct guest code and only makes a difference on buggy guest code running on older Arm cores (since ARMv7 and above handle unaligned accesses correctly in hardware).

That said, we do nowadays have better support in the generic code for emitting relatively efficient alignment checks; we just haven't bothered to wire these up to the Arm codegen yet. If somebody wanted to write QEMU patches to add that support we'd accept them. (Roughly, the code in target/arm/translate.c would need to add MO_ALIGN to the memop flags when generating guest loads and stores when the guest CPU is in a state that means unaligned accesses should trap; this may differ between different architecture versions and for different types of load and store insn.)

Comment: Hello, this answer has been done almost 3 years ago, is there an update on the current status ? Or does QEMU still not support this?

Comment: As it happens, yes, the handling of alignment faults has been improved very recently. You'd need to compile head-of-git QEMU from source to try it out, though. It ought to be in the next (6.1) release.

Comment: Hi, what is the current status of this?

Comment: I think this is now implemented in upstream QEMU (though there might be a few corner cases we don't check on, like AArch64 stack alignment traps and M-profile MVE alignment checking).